# android spinner -onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

I am a Beginner.  I have a problem with a spinner. I want to create a spinner by using onItemSelected method and to display that selected spinner item in TextView

But my program is not running in emulator. it says "Program stopped"..
what was my mistake in below program. Pls help me.. Thanks U..

My SpinOnItemActivity.java

```
package spinner.onitemsel;
import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

  public class SpinOnItemActivity extends Activity  
  {
    Spinner sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);;

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner_array , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);




            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {           
                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin_on_item );

                    sp.performClick();

            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {    
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp.setAdapter(adapter);

                String Name = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();

                TextView tview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtxt );
                tview1.setText(Name);

            }

 }
```

My activity_spin_on_item.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SpinActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/testtxt"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testtxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/testtxt2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Spin Txt" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

My logcat Report

```
12-10 09:58:40.988: W/Trace(837): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-10 09:58:41.168: W/Trace(837): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-10 09:58:41.198: W/Trace(837): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-10 09:58:41.878: D/dalvikvm(837): GC_CONCURRENT freed 51K, 6% free 2830K/2996K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 56ms
12-10 09:58:41.878: D/dalvikvm(837): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms
12-10 09:58:41.968: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
12-10 09:58:41.968: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{spinner.onitemsel/spinner.onitemsel.SpinOnItemActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:899)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:603)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:981)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:609)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at spinner.onitemsel.SpinOnItemActivity.onCreate(SpinOnItemActivity.java:35)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-10 09:58:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  ... 11 more
12-10 10:03:42.109: I/Process(837): Sending signal. PID: 837 SIG: 9
```

My Edited Code: Pls Check it out..

```
 package spinner.onitemsel;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class SpinOnItemActivity extends Activity  
 {      
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    Spinner sp;
    TextView tview1;
    int length;

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin_on_item );

                sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);


                adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_array ,           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                sp.setAdapter(adapter);
                sp.performClick();       
            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {    
                String Name = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
                tview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtxt );
                tview1.setText(Name);

            }

 }
```

Comment: post your logcat error report

Comment: i have attached my logcat report.. pls help me..

Comment: ji.. as ur update.. now i've following 2 errors.. 
1.spin cannot be resolved or is not a field
2. testtxt cannot be resolved or is not a field 
but in R.java.. itz present.. public static final int spin=0x7f070000; public static final int testtxt=0x7f070002; wat to do

Comment: @ user370305 
finally..as ur updated code, i got spinner output.. but textview still not display the selected item from spinner.. pls help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `Spinner sp` is **null**, So when code line `sp.performClick();` is executed in `onCreate()` the application crashes with `Null Pointer Exception`.

Because you are defining `Spinner sp` in above `onCreate()` so android doesn't find the `Spinner sp` from **Layout Xml** file. It should be after `setContentView()` so android nut shell has a reference of that Spinner for particular Activity.

**Solution:**

Put these lines,

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);;

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner_array , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

in `onCreate()` of Activity after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin_on_item );`

Something like,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{           
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin_on_item );

 Spinner sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);;
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_array , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 sp.setAdapter(adapter);

 sp.performClick();
}
```

**Update:2**

From your  `activity_spin_on_item.xml`  File.

Look at Parent Tag,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SpinActivity" >
```

In this the attribute

```
tools:context=".SpinActivity"
```

should be `tools:context=".SpinOnItemActivity"`

Comment: i put tat two lines in my  onCreate() method after setContentView() as you say..
Still my program is not running..   it says "Program stopped" wat to do..

Comment: Stil i hav tat same problem.. i have attached my edited code and logcat .. pls check it out..

Comment: ji.. as ur update..

now i've following 2 errors..

spin cannot be resolved or is not a field
testtxt cannot be resolved or is not a field
but in R.java.. itz present..
   public static final int spin=0x7f070000;
        public static final int testtxt=0x7f070002;

wat to do..

Comment: finally..as ur updated code,  i got spinner output.. but textview still not display the selected item from spinner.. pls help me..

Comment: Implement `OnItemSelectedListener` in your activity. Look at this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html . And register spinner for it. like, `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: so you can accept this answer as a correct answer. by right click on symbol left side of my answer. this will help you on SO for reputation. Thanks..

Comment: @bala - Welcome Buddy..! Now you can ask me for any android related question with just "@user370305" tag prefix on any comment. Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 2):

```
Spinner sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);;

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner_array , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

will come inside your `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`

---

Edit:
Then

```
 sp.setAdapter(adapter);
 TextView tview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testtxt );
```

will also come in `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`

Edit:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin_on_item);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

        TextView tview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testtxt);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        sp.performClick();

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,
            long l) {

        String Name = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
        tview1.setText(Name);

    }
```

Comment: @Shreya Shah 
i put tat two lines in my  onCreate() method after setContentView()..
Still my program is not running..   it says "Program stopped" wat to do..

Comment: Please post the logcat output in your question, so we can see where the error is.

Comment: @ShreyaShah - For `TextView` its not necessary, OP can put that line after `onCreate()` once `setContentView()` called.

Comment: @user370305, yes, I know. But its a good practice. So I just mentioned it.

Comment: @ShreyaShah  Stil i hav tat same problem.. i have attached my edited code and logcat .. pls check it out..