# Capturing optionsMenu spinner clicks

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am updating my api 8+ app for the reason that a large section of the target market no longer has a Menu button on their device.

My solution is not working.

So, I'm using ActionBarSherlock.

I've moved the buttons I needed to into the Sherlock menu, and they work ok.

But the activity I am changing had a Spinner which changed the data returned. 
I am trying to add the Spinner into the Sherlock menu (it does appear), but I can't capture any clicks on it.

Here is a screenshot. The top spinner is the new one; everything in the purple block is just there to compare.

[image]

This is the code I am using set the menu and capture the clicks:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Add Sleep Record").setIcon(R.drawable.btn_add)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Create Report").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_listview_pdf)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()
            .getThemedContext());
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity()
            .getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item,
            new String[]{"Last 7 days", "Last month", "Last 6 months", "Last year"});
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Date Range")
    .setActionView(spinner).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), SleepRecordAddActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    case 2:
        tryCreateReport();
        return true;
    case 3:
        String boop ="I am here";

        String x= boop;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

}

I've set the Spinner id to be 3, but the switch on onOptionsItemSelected doesn't ever trigger on 3.

This 'activity' is a SherlockFragment which extends from a SherlockFragmentActivity

Comment: What is "the Sherlock menu"? Why are you not using drop-down navigation? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Comment: The navigation is tab swipe activity. Two of the fragments show data which can be altered by date range, which can be selected from a spinner (at least, it could in my old tab widget method)

Comment: The 'Sherlock menu' is the options menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, turns out that it doesn't access onOptionsItemSelected at all. You just have to add an OnItemSelectedListener as usual.

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()
            .getThemedContext());
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity()
            .getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item,
            new String[]{"Last 7 days", "Last month", "Last 6 months", "Last year"});
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                    //do stuff
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //do stuff                
        }

    });

    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Date Range")
    .setActionView(spinner).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing the ArrayAdapter context at the action bar instead of at the class you're current writing methods in.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity()
        .getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item,
        new String[]{"Last 7 days", "Last month", "Last 6 months", "Last year"});
```

The first argument should probably be `this` instead.  That said The Spinner above this should probably stay pointing context at the actionbar.

[This particular answer is also relevant to compare with even if the question isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798429/1305064)